# Not able to insert flexslider before div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

Hi I downloaded flexslider from [woothemes.com](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/)
I have a page structure like below

```
<div class="parentdiv anotherdiv">
 <div class="child-div1">some buttons here</div>
 <div class="child-div2">some content here</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add one more child div before child-div1 using jquery. This child-div has markup for the slider.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
$(".child-div1").prepend('<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="path"></li><li><img src="path"></li></ul></div>');
});   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
animation: "slide"
    });
});
```

I included the necessary css and js files.Code is actually prepending. But I could see only one white bar. Slider isn't displaying. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".child-div1").prepend(function(){
        return $('<div class="flexslider">
                      <ul class="slides">
                         <li><img src="path"></li>
                         <li><img src="path"></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>').flexslider({ animation: "slide" });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.But no luck.Slider isn't showing up at all now.Is there any other way to append a div in another in js?